# How can I do this in Jade (pug)?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, pugjs

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <i class="ti-user m-r-5"/>
      Profile
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't know how to put **`i`** and "**Profile**" in **`a`**. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use online service to convert HTML to Jade, for example: http://html2jade.org/

Here is an answer:

```
html
  body
    ul.dropdown-menu
      li
        a(href='javascript:void(0)')
          i.ti-user.m-r-5
            | Profile
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my life!

Answer (score 1):

I found that the **[inline tags](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/pull/1323)** can solve it!

```
ul(class='dropdown-menu')
  li #[a(href="javascript:void(0)") #[i(class=['ti-user', 'm-r-5'])] Profile]
```